# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.a.Repository required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently learning Java. Can anyone tell me if I have Hibernate configured and am using JwtFilter for authentication, I get the error "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.foo.boo.repository.FooBooUserRepository" with code as image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7CkZ.png)

Hope everyone can help!

I try to find anyway on the internet to solve my problem but i can't.
I hope to find a solution or root cause can solve my issue.

Comment: don't put links to external sources, add all the relevant code/messages/ as formatted text in the question. Did you actually declare a Bean of that type?

Comment: This seems to be a good resource to fix the problem: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/3-ways-to-build-a-Hibernate-SessionFactory-in-Java-by-example.
I think in your case option 2 would be the easiest to test. Later on you could extract it to a `persistence.xml`.

PS: I noticed that you tagger the question with [tag:spring-boot]. If you use Spring Boot, you can use dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-data` which will make it a lot easier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.